# How to insert multiple rows into mysql using bookshelf js (and knex querybuilder) without using InvokeThen?

Tags: javascript, mysql, query-builder, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I need to insert multiple rows in MySQL table. I have been using *invokeThen* but *invokeThen* insert rows using multiple queries.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2) VALUES ("field1-value1","field2-value1");
INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2) VALUES ("field1-value2","field2-value2");
INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2) VALUES ("field1-value3","field2-value3");
```

Can I insert multiple rows with single query using bookshelf js (or with knex querybuilder)?

```
INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2) VALUES ("field1-value1","field2-value1"),
                                              ("field1-value2","field2-value2"),
                                              ("field1-value3","field2-value3");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing an array of objects to insert:

```
knex(”table_name”).insert([{row1}, {row2}, ...])
```